Probability of n uniform random values form side lengths of a polygon
Question: Suppose $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are iid random variables, uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Then what is the probability that $X_1, X_2\cdots X_n$ are the side length of a $n$ sided polygon?
My thoughts: I have convinced myself that forming a polygon with sides of length $x_1\cdots x_n$ will be possible provided no one value is greater than the sum of all the other values. Then, I thought that maybe the problem could be simpler if we use the density of the uniform order statistics, namely we compute the probability that $X_{(n)}>X_{(1)}+\cdots+X_{(n-1)}$, where $X_{(k)}$ is the $k^{th}$ smallest in $\{X_1\cdots X_n\}$. This gives
$$P(\text{no polygon}) = n!\int_0^1\int_{x_1}^1\cdots\int_{x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}}^1dx_n\cdots dx_1$$
but this appears to be wrong to me, since the last integral doesn't make sense.
What should I do differently, or is there another approach? Thank you very much.

Let $Y_k=1-X_k$.  These are also uniform on $[0,1]$, and each $Y_k$ is independent of $X_j$ if $j\ne k$.
$X_2+X_3+\ldots X_n\lt X_1$ whenever $Y_1+X_2+X_3+\ldots X_n\lt1$.
The probability that the sum of $n$ independent $U[0,1]$ is less than $1$ is $1/n!$.  So that is the probability $X_1$ is greater than the sum of the others.
So the probability any one is greater than all the others is $n/n!$.
So the probability they form a polygon is $$1-\frac n{n!}$$

Ok this makes a lot of sense.. But the resulting integral seems unmanageable to me. Could you give a hint to the next step?
